# How to get out of hibernation if a batch file is repeating a hibernation command? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, boot, batch-file, hibernate

I need some help. I was making a script to automatically abort shutdowns from Windows Updates. I was intending to use *shutdown -a* and set it to repeat every 15 minutes but I wasn't paying attention. I put *shutdown -h* for hibernation instead. To make matters worse, I set it to repeat every 15 milliseconds instead of 15 minutes, so now it's stuck in a hibernation cycle. I tried cutting the power completely including unplugging the cord to hopefully end the Windows session, but when Windows boots up it is still hibernating and the batch file starts executing automatically before I can see the desktop to do anything. I need to somehow close out that Windows session to stop the script but do not know how. It's like I gave myself a computer virus. Thankfully I have a second desktop I can try and research this on. Thought I'd give SU a try. Thanks for any help.

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Try resolving the issue in [safe mode](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by clicking the option to "Turn Off the PC" while using the Windows 10 DVD under repair options. I wasn't sure that would do anything except turn it off with hibernation still being flagged upon next startup, but it appears to have ended the hibernation mode by doing this.